# how to get a list of dates between two dates in java

Tags: java, date

I want a list of dates between start date and end date.

The result should be a list of all dates including the start and end date.

Comment: [LocalDate.datesUntil()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate))

Comment: For those using groovy (using LocalDate): `(fromDate..toDate).each { println it }`

Answer (score 58):

## java.time Package

If you are using [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29), there is a much cleaner approach. The new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 incorporates the features of the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) API.

Your requirement can be solved using the below code:

```
String s = "2014-05-01";
String e = "2014-05-10";
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(s);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(e);
List<LocalDate> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();
while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
    totalDates.add(start);
    start = start.plusDays(1);
}
```

Comment: FYI, this exact same code would work using the [Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for those who cannot move to Java 8 yet. While java.time is not a drop-in replacement for Joda-Time, in this particular case the code happens to be the same.

Comment: You could set the initial capacity of the list by passing to the `ArrayList` constructor the number of days elapsed. `int initialCapacity = java.lang.Math.toIntExact( ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , end ) ) ;`

Comment: Note that Java 9 makes this use of `LocalDate` even easier with `Stream<LocalDate>`, eliminating the need to build your own `while` loop. See [the Answer by Hochschild](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35892853/642706).

Comment: What if i want to find and separate out Weekdays and Weekend using this? How do i do it?

Comment: LocalDate has a method to get DayOfWeek. Check that out.

Answer (score 54):

> Back in 2010, I suggested to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for that.
>
> Note that Joda-Time is now in maintenance mode. Since 1.8 (2014), you should use `java.time`.

Add one day at a time until reaching the end date:

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>(days);  // Set initial capacity to `days`.
for (int i=0; i < days; i++) {
    LocalDate d = startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i);
    dates.add(d);
}
```

It wouldn't be too hard to implement your own iterator to do this as well, that would be even nicer.

Comment: For alternative, see the [answer by Krishnan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23932946/642706) on this same question.

Comment: **TIP** Simplify that code with a call to [`plusDays`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays(int)). So this `LocalDate d = startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i);` becames this `LocalDate d = startDate.plusDays(i);`

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: The list doesn't contain end date, change i < days to i <= days

Comment: Could someone please update it with the current java.time api? It keeps confusing people (they keep coming with jodatime questions in 2019).

Answer (score 46):

Get the number of days between dates, inclusive.

```
public static List<Date> getDaysBetweenDates(Date startdate, Date enddate)
{
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(startdate);

    while (calendar.getTime().before(enddate))
    {
        Date result = calendar.getTime();
        dates.add(result);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: In general case the final list will not include the `fechaFinal` (ending date) when you are using `before()` method (which is equal to < operation). Instead the <= operation should be used. Since there is no equivalent method in `Calendar` class, you should increase the end date a bit.

Comment: Incrementing end date by 1 does not provide a full proof solution until we reset time information of enddate to 0

Comment: If using midnight as the `enddate` the last day won't show up.
Comparing time since epoch will fix this:

`while (calendar.getTime().getTime() <= enddate.getTime())`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 36):

## Streams

*Edit: Joda-Time is now deprecated, changed the answer to use Java 8 instead.*

Here is the Java 8 way, using streams.

```
List<LocalDate> daysRange = Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusDays(1)).limit(numOfDays).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: numofDays can be found as long numofDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);

Comment: If you are using Java 8 and later, there is no need to be using the *Joda-Time* library. The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See the [Answer by Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42344215/642706).

Comment: Why do I need to add +1 to numOfDays to get the endDate into list also?

Comment: @pipilam you don't add +1 to numOfDays, you add 1 to the day you are iterating on

Answer (score 17):

please find the below code.

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

String str_date ="27/08/2010";
String end_date ="02/09/2010";

DateFormat formatter ; 

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date  startDate = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
Date  endDate = (Date)formatter.parse(end_date);
long interval = 24*1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour in millis
long endTime =endDate.getTime() ; // create your endtime here, possibly using Calendar or Date
long curTime = startDate.getTime();
while (curTime <= endTime) {
    dates.add(new Date(curTime));
    curTime += interval;
}
for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++){
    Date lDate =(Date)dates.get(i);
    String ds = formatter.format(lDate);    
    System.out.println(" Date is ..." + ds);
}
```

output:

> Date is ...27/08/2010
>    Date is ...28/08/2010
>    Date is ...29/08/2010
>    Date is ...30/08/2010
>    Date is ...31/08/2010
>    Date is ...01/09/2010
>    Date is ...02/09/2010

Comment: This wont work around the end of daylight saving time since that day has 25 hours. You will get the next day repeated. Example for Germany:  Date is ...30/10/2010  |  Date is ...31/10/2010  |  Date is ...31/10/2010  |  Date is ...01/11/2010  (Simple solution: add some hours (12) to the start date)

Answer (score 13):

### Recommending date streams

In [Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146218), you can use following new method, [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-):

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 28);

Stream<LocalDate> dates = start.datesUntil(end.plusDays(1));
List<LocalDate> list = dates.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The new method `datesUntil(...)` works with an exclusive end date, hence the shown hack to add a day.

Once you have obtained a stream you can exploit all the features offered by `java.util.stream`- or `java.util.function`-packages. **Working with streams has become so simple compared with earlier approaches based on customized for- or while-loops.**

---

Or if you look for a stream-based solution which operates on inclusive dates by default but can also be configured otherwise then you might find the class [DateInterval](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/DateInterval.html) in my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) interesting because it offers a lot of special features around date streams including a performant spliterator which is faster than in Java-9:

```
PlainDate start = PlainDate.of(2017,  2, 1);
PlainDate end = start.with(PlainDate.DAY_OF_MONTH.maximized());
Stream<PlainDate> stream = DateInterval.streamDaily(start, end);
```

Or even simpler in case of full months:

```
Stream<PlainDate> februaryDates = CalendarMonth.of(2017, 2).streamDaily();
List<LocalDate> list = 
    februaryDates.map(PlainDate::toTemporalAccessor).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

**With java 8**

```
public Stream<LocalDate> getDaysBetween(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    return IntStream.range(0, (int) DAYS.between(startDate, endDate)).mapToObj(startDate::plusDays);
}
```

Comment: I found it the best solution, just you could use LongStream instead IntStream to avoid casting.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should definitely work:

```
private List<Date> getListOfDaysBetweenTwoDates(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    List<Date> result = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.setTime(startDate);
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.setTime(endDate);
    end.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); //Add 1 day to endDate to make sure endDate is included into the final list
    while (start.before(end)) {
        result.add(start.getTime());
        start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With [Lamma](http://lamma.io) it looks like this in Java:

```
    for (Date d: Dates.from(2014, 6, 29).to(2014, 7, 1).build()) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

and the output is:

```
    Date(2014,6,29)
    Date(2014,6,30)
    Date(2014,7,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static List<Date> getDaysBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate){
        ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(startDate);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime(endDate);

        while(cal1.before(cal2) || cal1.equals(cal2))
        {
            dates.add(cal1.getTime());
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        return dates;
    }
```

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to create a `Calendar` instance, and start a cycle, increasing it's `Calendar.DATE` field until it reaches the desired date. Also, on each step you should create a `Date` instance (with corresponding parameters), and put it to your list.

Some dirty code:

```
    public List<Date> getDatesBetween(final Date date1, final Date date2) {
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar() {{
        set(Calendar.YEAR, date1.getYear());
        set(Calendar.MONTH, date1.getMonth());
        set(Calendar.DATE, date1.getDate());
    }};

    while (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) != date2.getYear() && calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) != date2.getMonth() && calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) != date2.getDate()) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        dates.add(new Date(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)));
    }

    return dates;
}
```

Comment: You do know that you use a deprecated API? Yeah., java date handling sucks.

Comment: I think the condition for the while is OR and not AND

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 9, you can use the [`datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-) method on `LocalDate`:

```java
public List<LocalDate> getDatesBetween(
  LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
  
    return startDate.datesUntil(endDate)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: This solution was already covered in the Answer by Hochschild.

Comment: The `datesUntil` method excludes the end date.  Since the question asked to also include it, a date should be added to it: `startDate.datesUntil(endDate.plusDays(1))`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class in the [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library represents a range of dates, and can be used for this purpose:

```
LocalDateRange.ofClosed(startDate, endDate).stream().toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at the [Date.getTime()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) API. That gives a long to which you can add your increment. Then create a new Date.

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
long interval = 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour in millis
long endtime = ; // create your endtime here, possibly using Calendar or Date
long curTime = startDate.getTime();
while (curTime <= endTime) {
  dates.add(new Date(curTime));
  curTime += interval;
}
```

and maybe apache commons has something like this in DateUtils, or perhaps they have a CalendarUtils too :)

**EDIT**

including the start *and* enddate may not be possible if your interval is not perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

With [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) , maybe it's better:

```
LocalDate dateStart = new LocalDate("2012-01-15");
LocalDate dateEnd = new LocalDate("2012-05-23");
// day by day:
while(dateStart.isBefore(dateEnd)){
    System.out.println(dateStart);
    dateStart = dateStart.plusDays(1);
}
```

It's my solution.... very easy :)

Comment: FYI, that code might be a bit more readable if instead of `compareTo` you used `dateStart.isBefore( dateEnd )`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
String str_date = "DD/MM/YYYY";
String end_date = "DD/MM/YYYY";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date startDate = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
Date endDate = (Date)formatter.parse(end_date);
long interval = 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour in milliseconds
long endTime = endDate.getTime() ; // create your endtime here, possibly using Calendar or Date
long curTime = startDate.getTime();

while (curTime <= endTime) {
    dates.add(new Date(curTime));
    curTime += interval;
}
for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++){
    Date lDate = (Date)dates.get(i);
    String ds = formatter.format(lDate);    
    System.out.println("Date is ..." + ds);
    //Write your code for storing dates to list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like as @folone, but correct

```
private static List<Date> getDatesBetween(final Date date1, final Date date2) {
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    c1.setTime(date1);
    Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    c2.setTime(date2);
    int a = c1.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int b = c2.get(Calendar.DATE);
    while ((c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) != c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) || (c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) != c2.get(Calendar.MONTH)) || (c1.get(Calendar.DATE) != c2.get(Calendar.DATE))) {
        c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        dates.add(new Date(c1.getTimeInMillis()));
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `before()` or `after()` methods to compare two `Calendar` instances ?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple solution for get a list of dates

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
public class DateList
{

public static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {

    Date dt = new Date();
    System.out.println(dt);

        List<Date> dates = getDates("2017-01-01",dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        //IF you don't want to reverse then remove Collections.reverse(dates);
         Collections.reverse(dates);
        System.out.println(dates.size());
    for(Date date:dates)
    {
        System.out.println(date);
    }
 }
 public static List<Date> getDates(String fromDate, String toDate)
 {
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

    try {

        Calendar fromCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromCal.setTime(dateFormat .parse(fromDate));

        Calendar toCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        toCal.setTime(dateFormat .parse(toDate));

        while(!fromCal.after(toCal))
        {
            dates.add(fromCal.getTime());
            fromCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return dates;
 }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). This work is *much* more easily accomplished using the modern classes.

Answer (score 0):

A tail-recursive version:

```
public static void datesBetweenRecursive(Date startDate, Date endDate, List<Date> dates) {
    if (startDate.before(endDate)) {
        dates.add(startDate);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(startDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        datesBetweenRecursive(calendar.getTime(), endDate, dates);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as Jules Rogerson's but recursive instead of iterative

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing one of the above solutions. As adding 1 day to end date sometimes adds an extra day beyond the end date.

```
    public static List getDaysBetweenDates(Date startdate, Date enddate)
    {
        List dates = new ArrayList();
        Calendar startDay = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(startdate);
        Calendar endDay = new GregorianCalendar();
        endDay.setTime(enddate);
        endDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        endDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        endDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        endDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        endDay.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        while (calendar.getTime().before(endDay.getTime())) {
            Date result = startDay.getTime();
            dates.add(result);
            startDay.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        return dates;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method for getting dates between two dates, including / w.o. including business days. It also takes source and desired date format as parameter.

```
public static List<String> getAllDatesBetweenTwoDates(String stdate,String enddate,String givenformat,String resultformat,boolean onlybunessdays) throws ParseException{
        DateFormat sdf;
        DateFormat sdf1;
        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
          SimpleDateFormat checkformat = new SimpleDateFormat(resultformat); 
          checkformat.applyPattern("EEE");  // to get Day of week
        try{
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(givenformat);
            sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(resultformat);
            stdate=sdf1.format(sdf.parse(stdate));
            enddate=sdf1.format(sdf.parse(enddate));

            Date  startDate = (Date)sdf1.parse( stdate); 
            Date  endDate = (Date)sdf1.parse( enddate);
            long interval = 24*1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour in millis
            long endTime =endDate.getTime() ; // create your endtime here, possibly using Calendar or Date
            long curTime = startDate.getTime();
            while (curTime <= endTime) {
                dates.add(new Date(curTime));
                curTime += interval;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++){
                Date lDate =(Date)dates.get(i);
                String ds = sdf1.format(lDate);   
                if(onlybunessdays){
                    String day= checkformat.format(lDate); 
                    if(!day.equalsIgnoreCase("Sat") && !day.equalsIgnoreCase("Sun")){
                          dateList.add(ds);
                    }
                }else{
                      dateList.add(ds);
                }

                //System.out.println(" Date is ..." + ds);

            }


        }catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }finally{
            sdf=null;
            sdf1=null;
        }
        return dateList;
    }
```

And the method call would be like :

```
public static void main(String aregs[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(getAllDatesBetweenTwoDates("2015/09/27","2015/10/05","yyyy/MM/dd","dd-MM-yyyy",false));
    }
```

You can find the demo code : [Click Here](http://goo.gl/aTYL8M)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<LocalDate> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();
popularDatas(startDate, endDate, totalDates);
System.out.println(totalDates);

private void popularDatas(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, List<LocalDate> datas) {
    if (!startDate.plusDays(1).isAfter(endDate)) {
        popularDatas(startDate.plusDays(1), endDate, datas);
    } 
    datas.add(startDate);
}
```

Recursive solution

Answer (score 0):

This will add all dates between two dates and It will add current dates and then new dates will be added based on loop condition.

```
private void onDateSet(){
    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance(),startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.set(currentYear,currentMonthOfYear,currentDayOfMonth);
    endDate.set(inputYear,inputMonthOfYear,inputDayOfMonth);
    datesToAdd(startDate,endDate);
    }

    //call for get dates list
    private List<Date> datesToAdd(Calendar startDate,Calendar endDate){
                    List<Dates> datesLists = new List<>();
                    while (startDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) != endDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) ||   
                           startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) != endDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) ||
                           startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) != endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {

                             datesList.add(new Date(startDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), startDate.get(Calendar.DATE));

                             startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);//increas dates

                         }
                         return datesList;
                }
```

Comment: FYI, this code uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: I didn't use java.time classes. I used 
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
I am using Java 8 all are working properly.

Comment: **Do *not* use `Calendar` and `Date`.** They are now replaced by the java.time classes. Those old classes are confusing, poorly designed, and flawed. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all agreed to replace those legacy classes with the java.time classe; see [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Suggesting `Date` and `Calendar` in 2017 is ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get a list of dates between two dates in **Clojure**:

```
(loop [current-date from-date
                end-date to-date
                days []]
           (if (time/before? current-date end-date)
             (recur (time/plus current-date (time/days 1)) end-date
               (conj days current-date))
             days))
```