# Convenient way to generate dates of year

Tags: java

I would like to ask what is the most suitable way to create List of Dates for specific year to hold the dates of this year.

I have written the following and it works fine.
However,I am not sure that this the most convenient way.

```
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2012, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
        Date startDate = cal.getTime();

        cal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
        Date endDate = cal.getTime();


        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(startDate);

        while (calendar.getTime().before(endDate)) {
            Date date= calendar.getTime();
            dates.add(date);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just simplify that:

```
int startYear = 2012;
int endYear = 2013;

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(startYear, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
while(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) < endYear){
    dates.add(cal.getTime());
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar as [how to get a list of dates between two dates in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java)

With [Lamma](http://lamma.io) one can easily construct date range:

```
    for (Date d: Dates.from(2014, 6, 29).to(2014, 7, 1).build()) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

And the output is:

```
Date(2014,6,29)
Date(2014,6,30)
Date(2014,7,1)
```