# how to get a list of dates between two dates in java ? How to include/exclude start date/end date also?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have tried the example given in stack overflow 
[how to get a list of dates between two dates in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java)

The code works perfectly. But there is a small problem.  I don't get the end date also in my List. How do I choose to include/exclude the start date and include the end date ?
Do, I do that manually by using remove() and add() or can Joda API do that for me?

Comment: This question makes no sense without some discrete time step. Do you want the dates between them that change in seconds? hours?

Comment: As far as I know, my library [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/DateInterval.html) is the only API with configurable inclusive or exclusive interval boundaries. In other APIs like Joda-Time, you have first to add a day to make an exclusive end date inclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based [on API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html), it seems there is no direct way to choose include.

One hack may be, just add +1 to number of days.

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays()+1;
for (int i=0; i < days; i++) {
    LocalDate d = startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i);
    dates.add(d);
}
```

Comment: While your answer satisfies OP problem, IMO this question shows tons of lack of effort from him/her.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: sort of agree. Well, I couldn't help anything for that except voting for close.

Comment: I am new to the huge Joda API. So, i wanted to know if someone already knew the answer to that.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

### Half-open

Date-time work commonly uses the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time where the beginning is *inclusive* and the ending is *exclusive*. I believe consistent use of this approach in both your code and in your users’ business makes life much easier, avoiding amibiguities that can result in misunderstandings or errors.

The java.time classes use the Half-Open approach. Keep that in mind when using [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html), `Duration`, and [`ChronUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) classes.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 2 , 14 );

List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>( (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ) ; 
LocalDate ld = start ;
while( ld.isBefore( stop ) ) {  // Half-open approach, ending is exclusive.
    dates.add( ld );
    // Set up the next loop.
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

If you insist on that ending date to be inclusive, add a day to the input.

```
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 2 , 14 ).plusDays( 1 );  // Effectively making ending date inclusive.
```

…or (A) change the logic of the `while` test from `isBefore` to `! isAfter`, and (B) add one to the initial capacity of the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>( ( (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ) + 1 ) ; // Add one to accommodate inclusive ending (*not* Half-Open).
LocalDate ld = start ;
while( ! ld.isAfter( stop ) ) {  // Ending is inclusive (*not* Half-Open). So using "not after" logic rather than "is before". 
    dates.add( ld );
    // Set up the next loop.
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

### `Stream<LocalDate>`

By the way, this code gets simpler in Java 9 where you can get a `Stream<LocalDate` from [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-) method. That call returns a sequential ordered stream of dates.

A variant of that method lets you specify an amount to increment the dates. So, for example, instead of the default of single day increment, you can increment by two to get every-other-day.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).