# Fill Array With incremented Date value in Android

Tags: android, arrays, auto-increment

//Well i have gone through so many tutorial but coudlnt find my thing so i am here to put  up my query
i have two `DatePicker` `FromDate` and `ToDate` 
What i want is when User selext the date it should come in a `String Array` of Dates
suppose my date is `Start_Date="1/09/2012"` i want to fill Array like

```
String[] Date Arrau= {"1/09/2012","2/09/2012","3/09/2012","4/09/2012"}
```

What i have done is

```
    DateDifference=Integer.parseInt(EndDate)-Integer.parseInt(StartDate);

SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Date myDate= null;
    try {
        myDate= sdf.parse(StartDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date newFirstDate= new Date(myDate.getDate()); // 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    for(int i=0;i<=DateDifference;i++){
        Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(newFirstDate);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Date newDate= c.getTime();  
        DateArray[i]=newDate.toString();

    }
```

i am getting a null pointer Exception Error

it is giving me error Please help !!

Comment: please specify the error you are getting!And you question is not clear. what you mean by Start_Date object?what exactly you want.please refine your question.

Comment: @Hiral Pleasee see my updated question

Answer (score 4):

Create startDate and endDate like this

```
   Calendar startDate, endDate;
   startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
   endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        startDate.clear();
        endDate.clear();

        startDate.set(2012, 8, 1);
        endDate.set(2012, 8, 30); 
        ArrayList<String> list = getList(startDate, endDate);
```

This method is generating an arrayList.

```
public ArrayList<String> getList(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (startDate.compareTo(endDate) <= 0) {
                    list.add(getDate(startDate));
            startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        return list;

    }
```

Use this to format the date string

```
public String getDate(Calendar cld) {

        String curDate = cld.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + (cld.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
                + cld.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(curDate);

            curDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return curDate;
    }
```

Comment: if i dont want to send the DateFormat in "yyyy/MM/dd" It should be dd/MM/yyyy
it appreciate your help Thanks!!

Comment: i have Found another intresting answer 
Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java