# How to get business days between two dates in scala

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime

How can I get a list of business days (exclude the holidays and weekends) between two dates in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

I used Joda Time as the basis for working with times as recommended [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java), I just took the code and applied some Scala love to it!

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaIterator
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.Days
import org.joda.time.DurationFieldType
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants

object DateHelpers {
  // populate with your own holidays, this is a small subset of canadian holidays
  private val holidays = List(
      new DateTime("2012-01-02").toDateMidnight(),
      new DateTime("2012-05-21").toDateMidnight(),
      new DateTime("2012-07-01").toDateMidnight(),
      new DateTime("2012-08-06").toDateMidnight(),
      new DateTime("2012-09-03").toDateMidnight(),
      new DateTime("2012-10-08").toDateMidnight(),
      new DateTime("2012-11-12").toDateMidnight(),
      new DateTime("2012-12-25").toDateMidnight(),
      new DateTime("2012-12-26").toDateMidnight()
      )

  def businessDaysBetween(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime): Seq[DateTime] = {
    val daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(startDate.toDateMidnight(), endDate.toDateMidnight()).getDays()
    1 to daysBetween map { startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), _)} diff holidays filter { _.getDayOfWeek() match {
      case DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY | DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY => false
      case _ => true
    }}
  }
}
```

Comment: You could check out ScalaTime https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time it's a wrapper for JodaTime.