# Get the list of dates between two dates

Tags: java, date, jcalendar

I'm using `JDateChooser` and I'm making a program that output the list of dates between the selected dates. for example:

```
date1= Jan 1, 2013  // Starting Date

date2= Jan 16,2013  // End Date
```

then it will output

```
Jan 2, 2013...
Jan 3, 2013.. 
Jan 4, 2013..
```

and so on... until it reaches the end date.

I already finish working on the my program that once you click a date on the `JDatechooser` it will output the end date automatically. (selected date + 15 days = end dates)

I download the `JCalendar` or `JDateChooser` here: http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Very nice,but you forgot to ask question.

Comment: hahahaha i'm sorry, how can i output the list of dates between the starting and end date :D

Comment: Duplicate of [how to get a list of dates between two dates in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2689379/642706).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should try using [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), which will allow you to walk from one date to another...

```
Date fromDate = ...;
Date toDate = ...;

System.out.println("From " + fromDate);
System.out.println("To " + toDate);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(fromDate);
while (cal.getTime().before(toDate)) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
}
```

**Updated**

This example will include the `toDate`.  You can rectify this by creating a second calendar that acts as the `lastDate` and subtracting a day from it...

```
Calendar lastDate = Calendar.getInstance();
lastDate.setTime(toDate);
lastDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(fromDate);
while (cal.before(lastDate)) {...}
```

This will give you all the dates "between" the start and end dates, exclusively.

### Adding Dates to an ArrayList

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>(25);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(fromDate);
while (cal.getTime().before(toDate)) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    dates.add(cal.getTime());
}
```

## 2018 `java.time` Update

Time moves on, things improve.  Java 8 introduces the new `java.time` API which has superseded the "date" classes and should, as a preference, be used instead

```
LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate toDate = LocalDate.now();

List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>(25);

LocalDate current = fromDate;
//current = current.plusDays(1); // If you don't want to include the start date
//toDate = toDate.plusDays(1); // If you want to include the end date
while (current.isBefore(toDate)) {
    dates.add(current));
    current = current.plusDays(1);
}
```

Comment: That makes a nice change ;)

Comment: *cough* Joda Time *cough*

Comment: @MoritzPetersen Agreed, I thought it might be a little over kill for this, as we're actually calculating differences, just listing the dates.

Comment: can i change the date format like this MM-dd-yyyy?

Comment: `Date` doesn't care.  You can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to provide custom date formats if you need, but `Date` and `Calendar` won't care.

Comment: @MadProgrammeris there a way to add the dates to arraylist while looping?

Comment: @JohnPaulMagat Yes. In the while loop, instead of just printing the result to stdout, you can add the result to an `ArrayList`

Comment: @MadProgrammer    i tried this `while (cal2.getTime().before(newDateString)) {
      cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
     arraylist.add(cal2.getTime());
     }` but there is an error on the `add` why? or i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @JohnPaulMagat I added an example.  I can only assume that the `ArrayList` either did allow for `Date` objects or wasn't initalised

Comment: @MadProgrammer Still same error here is my implementation: `ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
   //get the days between two dates then print it 
  
   List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>(25);
   Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal2.setTime(toDate);
 
   while (cal2.getTime().before(newDateString)) {
   cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    dates.add(cal2.getTime());
    System.out.println(dates);
     }`

Comment: @MadProgrammer i try doing it with an iterator .. `String datelist=(format.format(cal2.getTime()));
     
     List<String> strlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
     
     strlist2.add(datelist);
     
     Iterator itr22 = strlist2.iterator();
     
     while (itr22.hasNext() ){
     
     List<String> strlist3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    // strlist3.add(itr22.next()); 
     System.out.println(strlist3);
     }`  but i dont know what is next to this.

Comment: @JohnPaulMagat `String` is not a `Date`.  `cal1.getTime()` will return a `Date`.  You `ArrayList` can't contain any other object type other then `String`

Comment: @JohnPaulMagat Your second code example doesn't make sense.  You're creating a new `ArrayList` called `strlist3`, adding a value to and then discarding it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i can't understand i just followed your example, the second code  is i'm trying to add the dates using iterator is that possible? i hope your not mad.. :D

Comment: @JohnPaulMagat Not mad ;) - My example creates a list of dates ...`ArrayList<Date>`, you're trying to use `String`, this is why you can't add values to your list

Comment: @JohnPaulMagat Okay, try something like...`String datelist = (format.format(cal2.getTime())); List<String> strlist2 = new ArrayList<String>(); strlist2.add(datelist); Iterator<String> itr22 = strlist2.iterator(); List<String> strlist3 = new ArrayList<String>(); while (itr22.hasNext()) { String next = itr22.next(); strlist3.add(next); System.out.println(next); } System.out.println(strlist3);`

Comment: i got it! already working.. `ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>(25);
   
   Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal2.setTime(toDate);
     
   while (cal2.getTime().before(newDateString)) {
   cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   
   String datelist=(format.format(cal2.getTime()));
   dates.add(datelist);
 
     }
   System.out.println(dates);
   System.out.println(dates.get(3));` now i can call the dates individually... thanks dude! :D