# How to get Date in the same format as String

Tags: java, date, date-format

I want to get the Date object which contains Date in the form yyyy-mm-dd after adding few months to existing Date object.
Using `DateFormat` object I have tried this way but its not giving the output as I want. How can I get this Date format in Java?
My code-

```
         Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();

        DateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
            Date d=cal.getTime();
            c.add(Calendar.MONTH,10);
            Date newd1=c.getTime();
            String news=sdf.format(newd1);
            Date dnew=(Date)sdf.parse(news);
```

String news has the date of format yyyy-mm-dd but when I use parse on that String it results Date object which is of format "Thu Jan 21 00:14:00 IST 2016". How can I get the Date object in the form of "yyyy-mm-dd" using String news in the above code.

Comment: You will want to tag the question with the language you are using.

Comment: I am using Java.. n i hv tagged nw

Comment: Read the documentation of SimpleDateFormat. It explains what `mm` means. Hint: it doesn't mean "month". Note that a Date doesn't have any format. It's just a number of milliseconds. You can choose how to transform this number of milliseconds to a string by using a DateFormat with the appropriate pattern. Your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It means "minute in hour", I just read..

Comment: A `Date` does not have a format.

Comment: also a duplicate of [change the date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958062/change-the-date-format) / [Change date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805762/change-date-format) / [change Date format in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934740/change-date-format-in-java) / [Change Date format Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504378/change-date-format-java) and many other instances of the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.util.Date doesn't have format. Its just Date.

You can make it print its values in any form you want, by using SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

You can try as this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String news = sdf.format(new Date());

    //for testing
    System.out.println(news);
```