# Java date format get all dates between two date values

Tags: java, datetime

I am writting a java application and I just started with java `Date`. What I am trying to do is to read a `json` that contains two date stamps that look like this: `2015-05-20T17:24Z[UTC]` . After I read the two dates I want to take only the objects that have time stamp between the two dates I have just read. Can anyone help me on how to work with this format?

Comment: Parse the format to a `java.util.Date` and use the `compareTo()` or `before()` and `after()` methods. Or put the dates into a query etc., depending on how `I want to take only the objects that have time stamp between the two dates` would/should be implemented (hint: details needed).

Comment: Which Java version? Are you using Java 8? (please say yes) ... If so, please have a look at the new Java 8 DateTime API: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/

Comment: @DaDaDom I am using java 6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785643/get-the-list-of-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: @dres Please post additional information in the Question rather than comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse the date use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm'Z'[ZZZ]" );
Date date = sdf.parse( "2015-05-20T17:24Z[UTC]" );
```

Then either loop over the objects you want to filter and check `object.date.compareTo(startDate) >= 0` and `object.date.compareTo(endDate) <= 0` etc.

Alternatively use a sorted map with the objects' date as key.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<Date> getDaysBetweenDates(Date startdate, Date enddate)
{
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(startdate);

    while (calendar.getTime().before(enddate))
    {
        Date result = calendar.getTime();
        dates.add(result);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return dates;
   }
```

Function above will list all the valid date objects between two dates

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8

Start by converting the `String` value to something which is comparable...

```
String text = "2015-05-20T17:24Z[UTC]";
ZonedDateTime from = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

Now, (obviously), you need a `to` date as well, but the conversion is the same process.  When you need to, convert the value you want to compare to a `ZonedDateTime` object (as above) and use it's functionality to determine if it's within the specified range...

```
ZonedDateTime from = ...;
ZonedDateTime to = ...;
ZonedDateTime date = ...;
    
if (date.isAfter(from) && date.isBefore(to)) {
    
}
```

Now, this is exclusive, if you want the `from` and `to` dates to be inclusive, you'll need to add a `isEqual` check for both the `from` and `to` dates (but it only needs to match one, obviously)

Now, you should be able to use something similar with using Joda-Time

Comment: I so want to convert all of our legacy software to Java 8 ... big part of the reasoning is the new date api.

Comment: @Thomas I died for `try-with-resources` when Java 7 came out :P - Know your pain ;)

Comment: Really? This deserved a downvote because? If I've done something wrong, I'd love to learn what so I can correct it and learn from it

Comment: Maybe it's because the OP said he's using Java 6 and this is on Java 8. If I had another vote, I'd upvote it twice :) - But don't mind it, I also received a downvote, also without explanation.

Comment: @Thomas Had the op mentioned java 6 in the original question, I would have done it using JodaTime instead :P but I'd already posted the answer before java 6 was mentioned. The version if java shouldn't effect the voting, as another user with a similar problem using java 8 would find it useful (I hope) ;) but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Create your from/to ZonedDateTime's as MadProgrammer said:

```
ZonedDateTime from = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

Then create Joda `DateTime`'s for from/to:-

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID(zdt.getZone().getId());
DateTime from = new DateTime(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

Then use Joda's `Interval.contains()` to check if each Instant falls within the interval - keeping in mind that `contains()` excludes the end date.