# Java/Scala best way to get difference between two DateTime objects as List of DateTime

Tags: java, scala, datetime

I need a method which returns a List of DateTime objects splitted by e.g hour

Example

```
DateTime start = DateTime.now() //2017-01-01 11:00:00
DateTime end =  DateTime.now().plusHours(10) //2017-01-01 21:00:00
```

Expected Result

```
List[2017-01-01 **11**:00:00,2017-01-01 **12**:00:00,2017-01-01**13**:00:00...
2017-01-01 **21**:00:00]
```

Right now i am using workaround that i am not happy with

```
while(start.isBefore(end)){
  start = startVar.plusHours(1)
  //do something with start    
}
```

Please, share your ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a list of dates between two dates in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many elements in the `List` you want, you can use `List.iterate`:

```
List.iterate(DateTime.now(), 10)(_.plusHours(1))
```

But if you have a start and end dates, you can use `Iterator.iterate` and then convert it to `List` (or just process the values in the `Iterator` directly):

```
val start = DateTime.now()
val end = DateTime.now().plusHours(10)

Iterator.iterate(start)(_.plusHours(1)).takeWhile(_.isBefore(end)).toList
```