# How correctly create string with formatted date?

Tags: scala

I have such 2 variables:

```
val dateFrom = "2018-01-15"
val dateTo = "2018-06-15"
```

How to make such string which has all days between 2 date:

```
{20180115,20180116,...,20180614,20180615}
```

P.S. As you can see format of date in final result is `"yyyyMMdd"`.

Thats what I try right now:

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Days}

def getDaysInBetween(from: DateTime, to: DateTime): Int = Days.daysBetween(from, to).getDays

def getDatesInBetween(from: DateTime, to: DateTime): Seq[DateTime] = {
  val days = getDaysInBetween(from, to)
  (0 to days).map(day => from.plusDays(day))
}
```

`getDatesInBetween` function return collection of date in DateTime format.

Comment: What is `DateTime` and `Days`? Some antediluvian jodatime api?

Comment: You are right. In that example which I try I use `joda`. Check my post again please. I add import of package.

Comment: Ok... And why exactly are you trying to use jodatime? It has been made obsolete by java 1.8 release back in 2014...

Comment: Well, ok. Can you show me example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23932946/2707792