# How to make a list of dates between two dates

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a list of dates that are included between two dates. Here is how I tried to do it :

```
public void fillDates() {
        long diffInMillis = Math.abs(secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime());
        long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        for (int i=0; i <= diff; i++) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+i);
            Long date = calendar.getTime().getTime();
            String str = convertDate(date);
            dates.add(str);
        }
    }
```

`dates` is a list of strings, and `convertDate()` is converting a `long` date into a string date. But I think the problem comes from the lines above, as the same day is added to the list every time.

I know other similar questions exists, but I didn't find any that really helped me... But if you have an entirely different solution for me, don't hesitate ! I'm just trying to get a list of (string) dates between two dates that are submitted by the user through `Date Pickers`.

Comment: **Don't use `Calendar`.** It's terribly troublesome. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `Calendar`, `Date` or `SmipleDateFormat`. [They're troublesome.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) You are better off using classes from the `java.time` package.

If both `firstDate` and `secondDate` are `LocalDate`s, then it'll become much easier:

```
List<String> dateStrings = firstDate.datesUntil(secondDate.plusDays(1))
    .map(date -> date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that `datesUntil` exists since Java 9. For Java 8, this is a helper method instead:

```
public static Stream<LocalDate> datesUntil(LocalDate from, LocalDate toExclusive) {
    long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, toExclusive);
    return Stream.iterate(from, t -> t.plusDays(1))
        .limit(daysBetween);
    }
```