# How to get date between start date & end date in material date range picker

Tags: android, date, material-components-android

when using material date range picker i can only get the start date & end date, is it possible to get date between start date & end date ? if it is possible how can i achieve that ?

i've looking at documentation in material.io,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get a list of dates between two dates in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method that does. but you can do it with the **Calander** class
the trick is created two instances of calander for the `start` date and another for the `end` date, with a `while` loop you can check if the start `date` is before the `end` date by adding a day to the `start` date each `loop iteration`.

here is an example how to do it for me I save the dates as a **long** :

```
 ArrayList<Long> dates = new ArrayList<>(); // the list to store all the dates 
 MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
 builder.setTitleText("Select rang");
 MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long, Long>> materialDatePicker = builder.build();
 materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Test");
 materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Pair<Long, Long>>() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClick(Pair<Long, Long> selection) {
                if (selection.first != null && selection.second != null) {
                    // start date
                    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                    start.setTimeInMillis(selection.first);
                    // end date 
                    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                    end.setTimeInMillis(selection.second);
                    
                    while (start.before(end)) {
                        start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // add one day 
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPositiveButtonClick: " + start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));// show all the day between end and start  
                        dates.add(start.getTimeInMillis());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

For more information see the [Field Manipulation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#field-manipulation) of the [Calander](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar) class